# Want to select only one radio button from the list

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've as asp.net design coding as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rad" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I run this, I was able to select all the radio buttons.. But I want to select only one.. How to do that..?

Comment: Run "this"? Run what?

Answer (score 5):

Assign the [GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Category1" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Category1" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="Category1" />
```

I have not tested this but it should work.  There is also a RadioButtonList control you might want to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Take a look at the w3c docs on radio buttons for detailed info on the base control: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio

Comment: @Johan there is no documentation from w3.org specifically on radiobuttonlist.  W3schools has it's uses.

Comment: @Johan fixed the w3schools link :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%RadioButton1.ClientID%>").change(function(){//server control so use ClientID
    //when RadioButton1 will change this will fire
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***u should add GroupName for your radio buttons..!!***

```
 <table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rad" GroupName="Radio" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="Radio" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="Radio" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: u should add GroupName for your radio buttons..!!